# Privilege Escalation TTY error while using sudo /usr/bin/vi command

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, privilege-escalation, sudo

I am currently trying to escalate my privileges on an Ubuntu box. When I enumerated the server and run "sudo -l" command, I found out **/usr/bin/vi** set to (root) NOPASSWD.

```
(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vi /var/www/html/*
```

Then I wanted to use **vi** for my purpose to escalate my privs to root, so I wanted to create a file with running the command below, so I can run my shell in vi.

```
sudo /usr/bin/vi somefile.txt
```

Then I got this error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

If someone help me with this issue, it is really appreciated.

- I just would like to able to run this command without error:

  `sudo /usr/bin/vi somefile.txt`

Comment: Just spawn a tty shell: https://netsec.ws/?p=337

Comment: @AndrewMorozko that would migitage the error that is posted in the question, but it wouldn't solve OPs problem: 'somefile.txt' does not match '/var/www/html/*'. That's the reason, askpass is even called. (Yet, vi wouldn't work great without a tty, I recon)

Comment: @TobiNary is right. Spawning shell and the absolute path issue are different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know exactly what you are talking about and you are almost on the right track.

the `sudo` is letting you run `/usr/bin/vi` but in the same way you can't just do `sudo vi somefile.txt`, maybe there is a reason you can't do `sudo /usr/bin/vi somefile.txt`

For those wondering, I am hesitant to give an exact answer because this is an active CTF and it is discouraged to give the solution until it has been retired.

Comment: Hi, you are right I am exactly trying to find that reason

Comment: Like I said, I am not going to spoil it directly, but think about the output of your `sudo -l`

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is all about reading the sudo -l command's result well as @vsja mentioned in the comments. Focusing on the results and the operation system my research ended up with [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421574/sudo-l-says-i-can-sudoedit-a-file-but-wont-let-me), which mentions to use the absolute path given in the `sudo -l` output.